# How To use Where instead of Group by?

Tags: sql, group-by, sas, where-clause, proc

I wrote a query , that gives me this Output :

[image]

(This is Just a sample obviously the Output Table contains 300000 rows approximatly)

And This is my Query :

```
  proc sql;
  create Table Output as 
  select ID_User, Division_ID, sum(conta) as Tot_Items, max(Counts) as Max_Item
  from (select c.ID_User , c.Div_ID as Division_ID, ro.code as Mat, count(*) as Counts
  from Ods.R_Ordini o
  inner join DMC.Cust_Dupl c
   on User_ID = ID_User
  inner join ods.R_Nlines ro
   on ro.Orders_Id = o.Id_Orders AND RO.SERVICE = 0
  inner join ods.R_Mat m
   on ro.Mat_Id = Id_Mat and flag = 0
  group by 
      ID_User,
      C.Division_ID,
      Ro.Code
      Having Counts > 1
     )
  group by
  Id_User,
  Division_ID
  Order by 
  Tot_Item DESC
  ;
  quit;
```

So , What i want is to re-write this Query , but instead of the Group by i want to use the Where Condition , (WHERE=(DIVISION_ID=3)) this is the condition.

I tried several attempts , with some i got errors , and with others i did got an output , but the output was not like the original one.

any help would be much appreciated , thank you.

Comment: Just add `where division_id = 3` before the `group by`.

Comment: I already Tried That But i still Get an Error !!!

Comment: Oh , wait , i know where is my Error , solved , Thank you.

Comment: Spread the knowledge, you can answer your own question

Answer (score 0):

The SAS data set option `(where=(<where-expression>))` can only be coded adjacent to a data set name.  So the option would have to be applied to the data set containing the column `div_id` that is the basis for computed column `division_id`. That would be table alias `c`

```
DMC.Cust_Dupl(where=(div_id=3)) as c
```

Or just use a normal SQL where clause

```
…
)
where division_id=3
group by …
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use WHERE DIVISION_ID=3 before group by.

### select ID_User, Division_ID, sum(conta) as Tot_Items, max(Counts) as Max_Item from (select c.ID_User , c.Div_ID as Division_ID, ro.code as Mat, count(*) as Counts from Ods.R_Ordini o inner join DMC.Cust_Dupl c on User_ID = ID_User inner join ods.R_Nlines ro on ro.Orders_Id = o.Id_Orders AND RO.SERVICE = 0 inner join ods.R_Mat m on ro.Mat_Id = Id_Mat and flag = 0 WHERE DIVISION_ID=3 group by ID_User, C.Division_ID, Ro.Code Having Counts > 1 ) group by Id_User, Division_ID Order by Tot_Item DESC